# function pointer vs. macro vs. inline

Tags: c, pointers, emulation

I have a function that does some checks and reads from arrays of bytes:

```
uint8 ReadMem(uint16 addr) {
    if (addr >= 0x8000) return ROM[addr];
    if (addr <  0x2000) return RAM[addr];
    // some more complex checks here
    return OPEN_BUS;
}
```

Since it's used by an emulator core, it's called millions of times per second. I wonder what is its overhead in general, compared to 3 options: inline, macro and calling it by a pointer.

The first 2 options aren't that good, because the function isn't small, and it's called by another one, that's embedded for most of the opcodes, and if being inlined, it dramatically increases compilation time and exe size. And to test how a function pointer will work, I'd have to do refactoring. There's an option to only compile the core once, separately from the rest the emulator, but it'd also require refactoring.

So is it worth refactoring in the end? Will the call by a pointer be as fast as macro or inline, or maybe it'll even be faster? Pitfalls for each method wouldn't be so important probably, since the function is quite simple, it's just a bit long. And very frequent.

Comment: If anything, I'd expect an indirect call (through a pointer) to be slightly slower than a normal function call.

Comment: Hmmm > I might try `#define ReadMem(addr) (ReadF[addr>>8](addr))` for speed.

Comment: Why not simple try the various methods and rate them yourself?  As I see it, without your code, data set and platform and compiler, there is no way to assess what is best.

Comment: Sidenote: Whatever code `OPEN_BUS` is, how do you differentiate that from valid data? Re the question: too broad, what does a benchmark say? How did you test? Which compiler/target/optimisations? Did you enable LTO? What is the structure of the project? Etc.

Comment: @Olaf it's valid too, that's a macro that returns the value that's been last in the data bus.

Comment: @feos: Quite bad idea for an emulator. One major feature of emulators is to signal an invalid address.

Comment: Are compilation time or code size really an issue on a modern PC? For an emulator go for the fastest execution speed: then you get headroom to monitor conditional breakpoints, watches etc. and still have hope to run the code emulation at full speed.

Comment: @Olaf it's mentioned that complex checks aren't displayed in the sample

Comment: @WeatherVane as I said, before I refactor the code 3 times, I'd like to have an idea what's expected to be best

Comment: I think you'll be surprised what kind of function compilers consider "small". This one is *definitely* small enough to inline.

Comment: oh, I thought I had eliminated the "dramatically increases compilation time and exe size" one.

Comment: @feos: That does not change the fact you retunr an in-band result, whatever your checks do. Have a look at `getchar` & friends for how to do it correctly.

Comment: Not sure how a function pointer comes into play here. It is not related to macros or inline functions. And for the other two, you should benchmark. But as a general rule, never use a macro where an `inline` function will fit, too. And that is mostly a matter of locality, because a good compiler will also inline static functions if their heuristics say to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> function pointer vs. macro vs. inline

```
MACRO -> Compile time resolved
INLINE -> Compile time resolved
Function Pointer -> Runtime resolved
```

> 1. MACRO and INLINE contents replaced at preprocessor stage and that was too fast. but it will not change at runtime that is disadvantage.
> 2. Function pointer hold the address of the function. this is useful for passing the function address to another function or calling that
>      function using function pointer.this process takes time more. because
>      of internally it has been done push/pop operation in stack.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the call by a pointer be as fast as macro or inline, or maybe
>   it'll even be faster?

Calling by function pointer means that you would have just another layer of indirection (function call is resolved at runtime). It also implies that such function cannot be inlined. It is unlikely that such method will offer any performance gain. In fact, I would expect just an opposite. There is a reason why C++'s virtual functions along with late binding are considered to be major performance bottleneck in large applications.

Answer (score 1):

A macro means that the definition of macro will be replaced by macro occurrence at each place. Inline also means that each function call will be replaced by function definition at the place of occurrence. The implication of macro and inline is that they result in larger code size as compared to function call. But inline and macro are faster in terms of execution speed. While a function call being slower because it has an overhead of stack management, argument passing, jump etc. So it's a trade off between two as per your priorities.